# Hide validations on form post back in aspx page

Tags: asp.net

I have put server side validations for each text box using `<asp:RequiredFieldValidator/>`. I have called ClearFields() method on page load that will clear all fields on the form when the button is clicked. The problem is that when the form gets posted and the fields are cleared, the validation message appears again. How to hide the validation messages on form post back. I am sorry, but its been years I have not coded in aspx and I can't find any solution online.

This is the textbox code:

`<asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Your Name *" ID="name"/>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="name" ErrorMessage="Name seems empty" CssClass="help-block text-danger"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>`

This is the button code:

`<asp:Button runat="server" class="btn btn-xl" Text="Send Message" ID="submit" OnClick="submit_Click" CausesValidation="false"/>`

Comment: Did u added  `Display:None` ?

Comment: @ShreyasBhandimatt where should I add this

Comment: `<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="name"  Display="None"ErrorMessage="Name seems empty" CssClass="help-block text-danger"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator> `

Comment: @ShreyasBhandimatt this removes the validation message

Comment: Remove `CausesValidation="false"` and try the above code once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are getting the validation message due to button used for clearing the fields. Set `CausesValidation` property of button to `false`:-

```
<asp:Button ID="ClearButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" Text="Clear" />
```

Also, please note `asp:RequiredFieldValidator` works on client side i.e on the browser it is not a server side validation.

**Update:**

Since you are clearing your fields on click of button, you can clear in `submit_Click` method itself after sending the email instead of page load. Ideally you should have a separate button to clear the form though.

Comment: `CausesValidation="false"` removes all the validations. I dont want this. All text fields are required so the validations should be there, but when the user clicks on the button,the text field values are submitted and the text boxes are cleared. So when the text boxes are cleared -ie when the form is posted back the validation messages should not appear

Comment: I have edited my question where I have added the code

Comment: No I have written that on the Page_Load() event. `name.Text = "";`

Comment: On form submit an email should go, the code for which I have written on Button_Click() event and when the page loads again after form submit, the text fields are cleared and the validation message should be hidden

Comment: @sumedha - Check my update, instead of calling the `ClearFields` method from page load, call it from button click event handler, once you have send the email.

Comment: @sumedha - Welcome :)